# Need to access SQLite tables from cmd line

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a DB created and accessed from an Android app I developed.  However, I'd like to access tables outside my app.  I've tried the command line tool 'sqlite3' and tried various SELECTS from the master, but it cannot find my DB file.  In the code it's '/data/data/databases/dbname' but specifying this doesn't work.  Further if I search my HD contents my DB is not found.
Where the H... is the DB file and how do I access it from outside my Android app?
Help greatly appreciated, and have a happy holiday season.

Comment: Any files created in the internal storage by an app are accessible only by the app itself. The only exception is if the device has been rooted at which point 3rd party apps will be able to access the internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

Try this at adb shell

```
run-as <package-name> sqlite3 /data/data/<packagename>/databases/dbname
```

For this to work, your app should be debug build (process should be visible in ddms)